# How to rewrite a javascript function in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xpath

I have a javascript function to get the xpath of an element. I need to rewrite it in jquery. Please help. Below are my functions:

```
$("a").click(function(event) {
    getXPath($(this));
}
```

This is a jquery function call.

```
function getXPath(element) {
    if (element.id!=='')
        return './/*[@id='+ element.id +']';
    if (element===document.body)
        return element.tagName;
    var ix= 0;
    var siblings= element.parentNode.childNodes;
    for (var i= 0; i<siblings.length; i++) {
        var sibling= siblings[i];
        if (sibling===element)
            return getXPath(element.parentNode)+'/'+element.tagName+'['+(ix+1)+']';
        if (sibling.nodeType===1 && sibling.tagName===element.tagName)
            ix++;
    }
}
```

I have this javascript function. But it returns xpath like `.//*[id=@undefined]`. Please help.

Comment: Or if somebody already has a jquery code to get relative xpath, please share the link.

Comment: What have you tried? Show the code you have in which you try to "convert" it and tell us where and what issue/s you have with it and we can help. We wont write the code for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must pass a DOM element to the function, which you can achieve e.g. as follows:

```
getXPath($(this).get(0));
```

If `this` refers already to a DOM element, you can use it directly instead of creating a jQuery object from it:

```
getXPath(this);
```

Even if you are using jQuery, this does not mean you have to use it for everything. Typically jQuery also introduces some overhead, but enhances readability.

Comment: Edited the question how I'm calling the getXPath() method..
getXPath(this) is not working. its not returning me anything..I tried getXPath($(this).get(0)); It is returning some path, but not sure if the xpath is correct.

Comment: @NaveenBharadwaj That's why he said to use `$(this).get(0)` or `$(this)[0]` to get the *element* rather than a jQuery selector. The xpath you're getting here should be correct.

Comment: I did not verify your function - was just helping to get it to work in a jQuery environment (which was the question as you stated it). If you give at least an example of the now returned XPath and the HTML in question, it might be easier to verify.

Comment: No I just verified. Its correct.. thanks for help :)